# How can i handle iPhone 4S low performance?

Tags: iphone, xcode, performance, frame-rate

I'm almost finished my application but I'm facing problem with iPhone 4S: performance. During the configuration part my application needs to load about 81 nodes and perform some cycle operation and I noticed that on my iPhone 4S the fps low to 12.4 out of 60.0.

I'm using texture atlas for handle my images but this doesn't seem enough. Do you have any advices for me? Maybe create a preloading SKScene in the middle? Load all of the texture atlas in a singleton class before launching the Main Menu?

Note: I'm using Xcode 7.1 with SpriteKit framework.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer with any detail.

Comment: @trojanfoe I really don't know how to explain. During the configuration part the application loads 10 images and several progress bar according to the user choice (handled by a for statement).

Comment: Start by using *Instruments* to track down where the bottle neck is.

Comment: @trojanfoe Ok I'm going to try. Honestly I didn't do this step because on iPhone 5 and 6 work really fluent and I thought was due to the low performance of iPhone 4S

Comment: Yeah maybe; you might be able to mitigate the issue using a more parallel-friendly approach.

Comment: @trojanfoe Did you mean using multithreading? Because, as I guessed, the problem is the low performance on iPhone 4S. Nothing wrong with my code according to Core-Animation on Instruments.

Comment: Use *Instruments* on the device and see if you can spot the bottle neck.

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm afraid I don't know what I have to look for. Sorry this is my very first experience on Xcode. I'm gonna read about instruments!

Comment: what is size of your nodes means width and height of texture